# Where is this CSS picking up from?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to explore CSS3 using this template http://www.themenesia.com/themeforest/truehost/

On the homepage, you see a call to action DIV as below

```
<div class="call-to-action">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>We are Truehost. The most trusted and dedicated <span class="id-color">hosting</span> provider.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a class="btn btn-extra-large btn-primary" href="#">Get This Now!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to understand how that id-color is picking up the color from green.css There are a lot of such color based css files for that template yet the homepage only picks up the id-color from green.css and show that text hosting in green color (`#1a8b49`).

Can anyone explain how this works, please?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the DevTools in your browser to see from where the CSS rules are being received? : )

Comment: Or rather, are you asking about CSS precedence rules? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498069/css-precedence-rules)

Comment: `green.css` was loaded last so it uses the definition of that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the header of [your link](http://www.themenesia.com/themeforest/truehost/) the `main.css` is referenced:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" id="main-css">
```

and there in line 41 you have:

```
@import url("colors/green.css");
```

Comment: Spot on. I changed that to red.css and it works accordingly :) So those many color CSS files are there for quick reference so we don't have to change all occurrences of green to red. Great!

Answer (score 1):

There are two criteria that the browser looks at when it decides on which CSS definition takes precedence.

The first is the order in which a CSS definition is loaded.  If all other factors are equal, the CSS definition that was loaded last on the HTML page is applied.

The second criterion is the specificity of the selector used to define a CSS property.  Let's say you have an element called `#container` which is displayed within an element called `#outer-container` like:

```
<div id="outer-container">
    <div id="container">
         Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

The last CSS definition to load could be

```
#container{
    background-color: pink;
}
```

But a definition that was loaded before the above could take precedence if it targeted the element with:

```
#outer-container #container{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This is because the second CSS definition is defined more specifically and with more thorough directions.

So, in summary: most of the time, the last loaded CSS definition is what gets implemented.  If you see a deviation to this behavior, it is most likely because another definition more specifically targeted the element you are looking at.